# John stdout to Hydra

Tags: hydra, john-the-ripper

I'm trying to use a John ruleset which seems to take up more space than I have available. Is there a way to pipe John into Hydra?

Comment: Why do you think hydra can handle this?

Comment: tungsten has a valid point. unless you ommited some info. whatever ruleset it may be that takes too much space on JTR, won't be any less somewhere else on the same computer !

Answer (score 1):

Hydra does not read from *STDIN*. It's like ramming your hand in a hole that isn't a hole.